# Obtaining Photos and Albums from Facebook using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to parse through and obtain my (my personal account not my app) albums from Facebook using the Facebook C# SDK. My goal is to grab the 10-12 most recent photos on my account. However, I understand I have to grab the albums first.

So, I've tried numerous things and ended up with the following url which returns a 400 Bad Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{my_user_id}/albums?access_token={my_access_token}
```

The token was obtained by calling:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type={2}&scope={3}
```

Any ideas why I'd be getting the 400?

Comment: My grant type is 'client_credentials' and the scope is 'user_photos,offline_access'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using grant_type = client_credentials you're requesting the an app access token. This will allow you to do various administrative actions for your application. See App Login in  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.

However, when using the user-parts of the Graph Api you need to perform a User Login using the oAuth Dialog. There are different ways of doing this such as with the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) which should be straightforward to use.

I've not found a nice way of doing this in a standalone web app using [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) without the  Javascript SDK (it's easy in a canvas app using the CanvasAuthorize attribute).

Here's an example of how to do it i a WinForms app http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx. It might work in a Asp.Net app if you could use the WebBrowser control. I've tried with WebClient but didn't have any luck.

**Update**

By looking at the sample here http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/534da45e108f#Samples%2fCSMvcWebsite%2fControllers%2fHomeController.cs it looks like you should be able to use the FacebookAuthorize attribute in a standalone site.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. It still says that I need to have an active access token. It seems to basically force an OAuth.

Comment: The sample is from a version later than 5.0.3. Things might have changed since that "official" release. You could try to grab the latest bits and compile them on your own. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 0):

Error code `400` means that the request was not correctly formatted. Verify that that the Final URL looks OK and try it in a browser.

> The request could not be understood by
>   the server due to malformed syntax.
>   The client SHOULD NOT repeat the
>   request without modifications.

I.e. that you try the following `https://graph.facebook.com/someuser/albums?access_token=1234` You would pre presented with the following:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token."
   }
}
```

If you provide an OK token and a real user, the result will probably look a bit different, but in your case you get a `400` because there is something wrong with the request.

Comment: So the URL looks okay but still throws a 400. Again, I can call https://graph.facebook.com/{my_user_id}/ and get the details of me.